# Convert a method to a generic one

Tags: java, interface

I created the following interface:

```
public interface ConverterInterface<T, S> {
    T convert(String id, S record, String event);
}
```

And All my Converter classes are implementing this one. Let's say I have multiple converters A, B, C, D...

For each class implementing this interface, I have a very similar load method like this:

```
private void loadA(String id, List<myObjA> objA, String event) {
    if (objA == null) {
        return;
    }

    // This is one class that implements that interface (I have multiple classes like this)
    MyConverterA converter = ...

    // Run over elements, call the converter and save it into an output list
    for (myObjA record : objA) {
        OUTPUT_LIST_A.add(converter.convertToEntity(id, record, event));
    }
}

private void loadB(...) { ... } 
private void loadC(...) { ... }
```

My goal is to convert this several load methods into a generic one so I can use the same according to my input.

I'm trying something like this:

```
private <S, T, V> void load (String id, List<S> data, T converter, List<V> output, String event) {
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (S record: data) {
        // Here I need to call the convert method from the interface
        output.add()
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: is the `load` method are in the same class that implements `ConvertInterface`

Comment: @Ali actually no :( but I'm following Polygnome's suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the List in:

```java
private <S, T> void load (String id, List<S> data, ConverterInterface<T, S> converter, List<T> output, String event) {
    if (data == null)
        return;

    for (S record: data)
        output.add(converter.convert(id, record, event));
}
```

Otherwise, if you only pass in the input, you can use the Stream API and `map`:

```java
private <S, T> List<T> load (String id, List<S> data, ConverterInterface<T, S> converter, String event) {
    if (data == null)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    return data.stream()
        .map(record -> converter.convert(id, record, event))
        .collect(toList());
}
```

The Point is that you only need two generic parameters, `S` and `T` and can specify `Converter<S,T>` as a parameter type (add variance if you need to).